# How to open an activity from a pager adapter?

Tags: android

I currently am using this code to try and open a new activity from an activity that's part of a pager adapter that's swiping between 3 activities.

```
    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements OnClickListener {
        private Context mContext;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context){
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
            ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) 
            inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
            collection.addView(layout);
            return layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            collection.removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ModelObject.values().length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];
            return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            //start new activity
            Intent i =  new Intent(mContext, SubjectActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

The code itself isn't throwing any errors, but when I run the app it stops the moment I click on the button. It wasn't having problems before I attempted to implement the onClick function so I am certain the problem is with how I have written that, but I can't figure out where. What is the issue with this method of opening a new activity?

Comment: From where you call onClick method? i didn't see it in your code

Comment: try set in your onClick . view.Context instead of mContext

Comment: onClick is the final function and I've set the button to respond to onClick in the xml. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @AndersSørensen can not resolve symbol context?

Comment: What else do you have ? when you just write view. do you have getContext?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean what other code do I have?

Comment: I don't have getcontext anywhere

Comment: i mean can you write view.getContext

Comment: I get can not resolve symbol getContext if I do that

Comment: Okey your way with mContext should work, im not sure why, try set a breakpoint and test

Comment: Ok thank you for trying